# Convert text to xml document

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a text file which contains string values:

```
January   
February  
March
```

I would like to extract these strings from a text file and add it to an xml document, see below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>      
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">      
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none">    
    <test name="Test" preserve-order="true">    
        <classes> 
            <class name="January"/>
            <class name="February"/>
            <class name="March"/>
        </classes>
    </test> 
</suite>
```

I am not sure as to what process should be implemented to get the above result, please help?

Answer (score 1):

Using XSLT 3.0 (as available with Saxon 9.7 PE and EE) or with Exselt you could use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" doctype-system="http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template name="main">
        <suite name="Suite" parallel="none">    
            <test name="Test" preserve-order="true">    
                <classes> 
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="unparsed-text-lines('input.txt')"/>
                </classes>
            </test> 
        </suite>        
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match=".[. instance of xs:string]">
        <class name="{normalize-space()}"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using XSLT 2.0 as available with Saxon 9 or XmlPrime or Altova you can use

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" doctype-system="http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template name="main">
        <suite name="Suite" parallel="none">    
            <test name="Test" preserve-order="true">    
                <classes> 
                    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(unparsed-text('input.txt'), '\r?\n')">
                        <class name="{normalize-space()}"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </classes>
            </test> 
        </suite>        
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: when I run this XSL Transformation in Eclipse. I get the following error:  FATAL [main] Main  - No embedded stylesheet instruction for file: file:/C:/xlstexample1/stylesheet.xml.

Comment: As said, the stylesheets are XSLT 2.0 respectively 3.0, so you need to use Saxon 9 to run them and make sure you set the initial template to be the one named `main`.

Comment: From my understanding main.xml should be a blank file ? which will be populated by XSLT transformation file ?

Comment: The transformation as shown does not need any input XML and does not expect any as you want to process a plain text file (named `input.txt` in the code, you can change that as needed). If you want to pass in a dummy input XML (or use JAXP which always expects some XML input) then change `<xsl:template name="main">` to `<xsl:template name="main" match="/">`. The input XML however then can't be a blank file, it has to be a well-formed XML document meaning it needs to have at least a root element.

Answer (score -1):

If i understood you, the only thing which is changing here are names of the classes.

I have created a simple script which splits all strings with comma and create separate classes.

You just have to copy the text form the document and add it to a new variable and the script will do the rest.

```html
<script>
var text = "example variable with some text";
var partsOfStr = text.split(' ');
for(i=0; i<partsOfStr.length; i++){
 document.write("&lt;class name=&quot;"+partsOfStr[i]+"&quot;/&gt;<br>");
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm afraid this code exhibits the classic bug when you try to write XML "by hand": you forget to escape special characters such as quotation marks, angle brackets, and ampersands. A vast number of StackOverflow questions are submitted by users who have received bad XML that was constructed by careless code like this.